# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error in Unity 2019.4+

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker-errors

After upgrading project from Unity 2018.4.19 (LTS) to 2019.4.5 (LTS) it stopped success build for iOS. There are apple linker error:
[image: XCode Linker Errors]

> **"_inflate", referenced from:**
> _inflate_stream in libSkyTrakSW.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)

> **"_zlibVersion", referenced from:**
> _Curl_unencode_gzip_write in libSkyTrakSW.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)

> **"_inflateInit2", referenced from:**
> _inflate_stream in libSkyTrakSW.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)

> **"_inflateEnd", referenced from:**
> _inflate_stream in libSkyTrakSW.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)

> **"_inflateInit", referenced from:**
> _Curl_unencode_deflate_write in libSkyTrakSW.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)

The project contains native C++ static library libSkyTrakSW.a, that was build in XCode from source code, so I can recompile it. I'm guessing that something was changed in Unity, because the same project with the same XCode version (10.3) was success built with Unity 2018.4 and failed with Unity 2019.4.

I've found, that this error related to not linked library **libz.tbd**, but I have linked this library as well.

Also I have added **Security.framework** as dependency.

The question is how to fix these errors? Maybe I need to recompile libSkyTrakSW.a library with some special flags or add some special flags in Unity project.

The same errors are with the latest Unity 2020.1.3. Help please. Thanks!

Comment: Does iOS build works for empty project?  Also, can you temporary remove the native C++ static library and security.framework for testing purpose? Maybe you will find the real issue by doing that.

Comment: Sure there is no zlib library that came with the one you mention?

Comment: No, there is no another libz library in the project. And I wrote above exactly the same project compiles success with Unity 2018.4. And yes, I was trying to remove Security.framework and libz.tbd with the same result. I can't remove static library because I'm using native calls from C# code.